# Implement the load more button in ajax form with codeigniter and javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, angularjs, codeigniter

I would like to create the "load more" button similar to facebook

http://www.ifadey.com/demos/14_load_more/

Currently , my approach is like this:

**in cilent side:**

```
$(".load").on("click", function(){
    $.post(action_url, {postID : post_id}, function() {
      $("chat").append("<div>....</div>");
    });
});
```

**in php side**

```
$post_id = $this->input->post("postID");
$return_list = $this->List_model->get_list($post_id);
echo json_encode($return_list);
```

This work fines and a traditional way, there is a problem , the code is messy as put all html tag inside jquery function, so I would like to know are there any more latest way to do ? e.g. angular / react.

But after reading some angular doc, I would perfer not to mix up angular and jquery.

Or actually has a plugin for this purpose already?

Thanks a lot for helping

Comment: Pass the data to a php file and generate the `html` and return it as a  `json` to append using `ajax` ??

Comment: Maybe not the "proper" way to do it (I do it all the time), but why not echo the html in the php instead of returning a `jSON` array?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31553329/how-to-load-view-more-comments-using-ajax-and-codeigniter/31554418#31554418

Comment: One reason not return html is it use with the mobile API so only data should return

Comment: add one condition before return html 
if($is_resposce_js){
return $data;
}else{
return $html
}